# ¿Cómo Calculo la Posición Final en la Rotación Arbitraria?

Tags: vb.net

Mi Problema Reside ahora en saber en que coordenadas poner el Left y Top de la Nueva Imagen. Para esto tengo la siguiente función:

```html
Public Sub RotarArbitraria(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox, Optional Grados As Single = 22.5F)
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim FreeFilePath As String = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Imagen.bmp"

        Dim Ima As Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
        Dim B As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim GRAF As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
        GRAF.Clear(Color.White)

        Dim LT As Single = 0.0F
        Dim TT As Single = 0.0F
        If Grados <= 0.0F Then
            LT = 50.0F 
            TT = -50.0F 
            GRAF.TranslateTransform(LT, TT)
            GRAF.RotateTransform(Grados)
            Dim L As Integer = -(Imagen.Image.Width / 18) 
            Dim T As Integer = -(Imagen.Image.Height / 18) 
            Dim H As Integer = Imagen.Image.Height
            Dim W As Integer = Imagen.Image.Width
            GRAF.DrawImage(Ima, L, T, W, H)
            GRAF.Save()
        Else
            LT = 50.0F 
            TT = -50.0F 
            GRAF.TranslateTransform(LT, TT)
            GRAF.RotateTransform(Grados)
            Dim L As Integer = -(Imagen.Image.Width / 18) 
            Dim T As Integer = -(Imagen.Image.Height / 18) 
            Dim H As Integer = Imagen.Image.Height
            Dim W As Integer = Imagen.Image.Width
            GRAF.DrawImage(Ima, L, T, W, H)
            GRAF.Save()
        End If

        B.Save(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.Load(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude hacer-lo así:

```html
Public Sub RotarArbitraria(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox, Optional Grados As Single = 22.5F)
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim FreeFilePath As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Temp.Bmp"
        Dim Ima As Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
        Dim B As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
        Dim GRAF As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
        GRAF.Clear(Color.White)
        Dim LT As Single = 0.0F
        Dim TT As Single = 0.0F
        LT = Imagen.Image.Width / 2
        TT = Imagen.Image.Height / 2
        GRAF.TranslateTransform(LT, TT)
        GRAF.RotateTransform(Grados)
        Dim L As Integer = (-Imagen.Image.Width / 2)
        Dim T As Integer = (-Imagen.Image.Height / 2)
        GRAF.DrawImage(Ima, L, T)
        GRAF.Save()
        B.Save(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.Load(FreeFilePath)
        Imagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    End Sub
```